# mysqldump goes nuts when first column is generated

Tags: mysql

So I have this table called breaks_mysqldump, which's first columns are generated.

```sql
create table breaks_mysqldump (
  custId int unsigned as (data->'$.custId') stored not null,
  custDataId int unsigned as (data->'$.custDataId') stored not null,
  data json,
  primary key (custId, custDataId)
);

insert into breaks_mysqldump (data) values 
('{"custId": 1, "custDataId": 1, "description": "Test 1-1"}'),
('{"custId": 1, "custDataId": 2, "description": "Test 1-2"}'),
('{"custId": 2, "custDataId": 1, "description": "Test 2-1"}');
```

Everything works fine, but `mysqldump` simply goes nuts...

```sh
$ mysqldump mydb breaks_mysqldump

...
INSERT INTO `breaks_mysqldump` (`data`) VALUES ,'{\"custId\": 1, \"custDataId\": 1, \"description\": \"Test 1-1\"}'),,'{\"custId\": 1, \"custDataId\": 1, \"description\": \"Test 1-1\"}'),'{\"custId\": 1, \"custDataId\": 2, \"description\": \"Test 1-2\"}'),,'{\"custId\": 1, \"custDataId\": 1, \"description\": \"Test 1-1\"}'),'{\"custId\": 1, \"custDataId\": 2, \"description\": \"Test 1-2\"}'),'{\"custId\": 2, \"custDataId\": 1, \"description\": \"Test 2-1\"}');
...
```

As you can see, the dump doesn't make any sense, incorrect formatting, repeated values etc.

Any idea how to fix this?

Both mysql and mysqldump are ver 8.0.28

Comment: This is listed as a bug https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=81926

Comment: Please file a bug at bugs.mysql.com -- sadly I think you ran into something that Oracle is going to have to fix.

You can look into other backup tools like Percona's Xtra Backup or the dump utils in MySQL Shell while you wait for this to be resolved.

Comment: Why not just store the primary key columns as normal columns? Why are you storing them in JSON?

Comment: This bug made my 300k row table blow up into a 1.3TB sql file, after doing delta zero's workaround it successfully generated 40kB file. (It did what op explains, but repeating the first 3 or so rows infinitely)

Answer (score 0):

I only found a workaround altering table's DDL :(

```sql
alter table breaks_mysqldump
add column _ int null first;
```

mysqldump now makes sensible output.

```sh
$ mysqldump mydb breaks_mysqldump

...
INSERT INTO `breaks_mysqldump` (`_`, `data`) VALUES (NULL,'{\"custId\": 1, \"custDataId\": 1, \"description\": \"Test 1-1\"}'),(NULL,'{\"custId\": 1, \"custDataId\": 2, \"description\": \"Test 1-2\"}'),(NULL,'{\"custId\": 2, \"custDataId\": 1, \"description\": \"Test 2-1\"}');
...
```

I'll also share some useful sql scripts I've used in production in order to work around this issue.

```sql
-- identify affected tables
select TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
from information_schema.COLUMNS
where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'mydb' -- your database
  and ORDINAL_POSITION = 1
  and EXTRA LIKE '%generated%';

-- run this to all affected tables
alter table XXXYYY add column _ int null first;
```

run mysqldump

```sql
-- identify affected tables again
select TABLE_NAME
from information_schema.COLUMNS
where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'mydb' -- your database
  and ORDINAL_POSITION = 1
  and COLUMN_NAME = '_';

-- run this to all affected tables
alter table XXXYYY drop column _;
```

Keep in mind you'll need to run `drop column` queries after importing your dumps, every time...

Hope this mysqldump's bug will be fixed soon.